# Wav file and midi playback not synchronised

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, wav, midi

I am working on a simple sequencer application in C++ using the Win API. My application plays drum beats using wav files, and chords and a bass line using midi. The wav files each play in their own threads as follows (error handling omitted):

```
while(_runThread)
{
    // Wait for the event telling us to play the sound
    WaitForSingleObject(_threadEventHandle, INFINITE);
    ResetEvent(_threadEventHandle);

    if(_runThread)
    {
        // Clear anything currently playing
        waveOutReset(_waveOutHandle);

        while(_sampleDataIndex < _sampleDataSize)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++)
            {
                if(_runThread && _waveHdr[i].dwFlags & WHDR_DONE)
                {
                    PrepareAudioBuffer(i);
                    _result = waveOutWrite(_waveOutHandle, &_waveHdr[i], sizeof(WAVEHDR));
                }
            }

            // Wait for the event telling us the device has completed playback to be signaled
            if(_runThread)
            {
                WaitForSingleObject(_waveDoneEventHandle, INFINITE);
                ResetEvent(_waveDoneEventHandle);
            }
        }
        _sampleDataIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

The PrepareAudioBuffer function simply loads samples into the buffer. The thread is activated by the following call from the timer:

```
SetEvent(_threadEventHandle);
```

Midi playback is achieved via the following:

```
#define MIDI_MESSAGE(volume, note, command) ((volume << 16) | (note << 8) | command)

midiOutShortMsg(_midiOutHandle, MIDI_MESSAGE(volume, note, command));
```

Both mid and audio playback are triggered by the same timer logic. However there is slight but noticeable gap between the playback of the 2 which I need to fix. I suspect this is caused by having the wav playback in a separate thread and waiting on SetEvent as well as any delays introduced by context switching. I know it is possible to play back both audio and midi in perfect synchronisation as applications such as Cubase, Sonar and so on do this. Any thoughts or recommendations gratefully received.

Comment: Which MIDI synthesizer are you using? What latency does it have?

Comment: The human ear is extremely sensitive to such time jitter.  An evolutionary trait that tells your brain in which direction you should run when you hear the rustle of a lion hidden in the tall savanna grass :)  Nothing simple about it, using the callbacks you register with waveOutOpen and midiOutOpen is important.  So is timeBeginPeriod and timeSetEvent to lower the clock interrupt rate.

Comment: @CL Thanks for your help. I'm using the Microsoft GS WaveTable SW synth, and I think it is this that is causing the issues. At very slow tempo's you can hear the wave file play distinctly before the midi. Frustrating! Not sure how to find out what the latency is, need to do a bit of reading.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply. I'm using timeBeginPeriod(4) to adjust the system timing but found timeSetEvent too inaccurate at millisecond levels below 10 (and CreateTimerQueueTimer was worse!). I didn't want to set the period with timeBeginPeriod any lower as it would increase resource usage on laptops. I'm using the callbacks.

Comment: The Microsoft GS WaveTable SW Synth was intended to be used for .mid file playback, not for real-time applications, and has horrible latency. Sequencers that want to synchronize wave and MIDI use their own built-in synthesizer (or plugins) and mix its output into the wave data.